# C# Validate Date Picker in WPF using IDataErrorInfo & INotify

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, validation

I am trying to validate Date Picker using IDataErrorInfo

I want to check if selected date is a week ahead also if selected date is in the past

What I've done so far...

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                DateTime seven = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+7);
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DepartureDate);

                if (columnName == "DepartureDate")
                {
                    //range between today and seven days ahead +7
                    if (dt >= today && dt <= seven)
                    {
                        result = valid;
                        return result;
                    }
                    //can't be in the past
                    if (dt.Date == today)
                    {
                        result = "Can't be in the past";
                        return result;
                    }
                    if (dt.Date == today.Date)
                    {
                        result = valid;
                        return result;
                    }
                }
```

.

```
<DatePicker Height="25" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource eTemplate}" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="424,170,0,0" Name="DepartureDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" FontSize="12">
            <DatePicker.DisplayDate>
                <Binding Path="DepartureDate" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </DatePicker.DisplayDate>
        </DatePicker>
```

Comment: Why do you need to validate a date picker?  Doesn't it restrict the input from the user already?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like:

```
     <DatePicker Width="100" Height="30"  >
        <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
            <Binding Path="DepartureDate" Mode="OneWayToSource" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:MyValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
    </DatePicker>

public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "ErrorContent");
        }
    }
```

Implementing your logic in the Validate method.

There is also an event on the control you could hook called DateValidationError. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.datevalidationerror(v=vs.110).aspx

If you wanted to do code behind.